# Alpine Linux: Mounting boot media: failed

Tags: alpine-linux

I installed Alpine Linux dualbooting with the instructions [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_on_HDD_dualbooting), and I was faced with the error "Mounting boot media: failed." The solutions I found online fixed the boot of the live ISO, not a sys installation, which in theory should not depend on boot media. What's going wrong here?
[Here](https://transfer.sh/get/179Nhwp/dmesg.txt) is the kernel log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `root` kernel option was not provided, and thus Alpine was attempting to mount the boot media which did not exist. Adding `root=<partition>` worked perfectly.